# typescript outDir setting in tsconfig.json not working

Tags: typescript, build, package.json, tsc, outdir

I can't seem to get the `outDir` flag working when used in `package.json`. Directory structure is pretty simple: `tsconfig.json` at the root level, together with a `src/` directory and a single index.ts file plus other directories representing other modules.

When running the `tsc` command on the index file, it creates a new one beside it instead of in the build directory. What am I doing wrong?

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build"
  }
}
```

My npm build script:

```
"build": "tsc src/index.ts"
```

I'm calling the script from the root dir of the project. Interestingly, running the same script with an `--outDir` flag works just fine.

Comment: Just a typescript thing I guess... ‍♂️

Answer (score 225, accepted):

When you pass in files for compilation with `tsc src/index.ts`, your `tsconfig.json` is ignored.

From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json
>   files are ignored.

Your npm build script should just be `tsc` without passing any files.

Comment: What?! WHY? Ridiculous.

Comment: Have no idea why it works like this, but the answer is 100% accurate.  Thanks

Comment: How do you tell the script where the .ts file you want to compile is?
If I leave off the path I get all kinds of errors?

Answer (score 42):

In my case it was being ignored because I had `noEmit: true` in `tsconfig.json`. For whatever reason, the files *still* were emitted, but in the same directory instead of following `outDir`.

The config file was read correctly and this error also appeared when using the flag.

Comment: Was extending [ts-config-single-spa](https://github.com/single-spa/create-single-spa/blob/main/packages/ts-config-single-spa/tsconfig.json), which has `noEmit: true`.

Comment: I added "noEmit": false and all finally my outDir was created and populated

Comment: Bravo. Saved me. Thanks.In my case a tsconfig.json file had been misconfigured. The symptom was loads of errors reported by 'react-scripts start', but none reported by 'npx tsc'.

Comment: THX for this usefull hint with noEmit.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using the [`incremental`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html) compiler option, you may not be getting output if you have deleted / modified files in your `outDir` but have not removed the `.tsbuildinfo` file.

My issue was a bit different, but Google brought me here - so figured others may also.

Comment: Thanks for deciding to post here! I couldn't figure out why `tsc -b` would only create my output folder occasionally. Turns out my `yarn:clean` would only `rm -rf packages*/dist`, leaving behind the `.tsbuildinfo` files!

Comment: Thanks for this. Note that all composite projects are incremental. I had to, similar to above commenter, rm -rf *.tsbuildinfo as a prebuild step in my build project

Answer (score 9):

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Keep the typescript files in src folder and keep the tsconfig.json in root.

In tsconfig json file add foldername for outDir in compilerOptions

```
"compilerOptions": {    
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
```

and run the below commands.

just cd to the root folder and type

> tsc

or

> tsc --outDir .

[image]

which will build the outDir folder with js and map.js files.

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10585

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I met the same problem.
Your should set the script as "build": "tsc" rather than "build": "tsc src/index.ts"

Answer (score 3):

Make sure "outDir" is defined under "compilerOptions"

I had it defined at the same level as "compilerOptions"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "node_modules/@types",
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your tsconfig file location instead of the file you want to build.

```sh
tsc --build mocks/tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me `tsc --outDir dist/` where dist is my output or destination folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).