# TypeScript import gives error importing Express with proper flags

Tags: typescript, express

I'm attempting to write an Express server with TypeScript. Everything is written from scratch instead of a CLI, so I'm sure there's an error somewhere in my setup.

I want to write `import express, { Application } from express` just as I have it in other servers I've written, but I get the error:

```
import express from 'express'
         ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:115:1
    115 export = e;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

TS Config:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "esnext",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

And the package JSON:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/knex": "^0.16.1",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.20.13",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "pg": "^8.0.0",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.4"
  }
```

Babel is currently unused. I've tried changing `module` as well with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by `"noEmit": true` as that prevents any output, so of course I wasn't seeing any changes after running 'tsc'.

I was seeing errors messages specifically when running `tsc server.ts` because running with arguments or flags will **ignore** the `tsconfig.json` and use default flags, so running `tsc server.ts --esModuleInterop` produced expected results.

This is why I'm running it all from scratch, so I can make stupid mistakes like this, I guess. Hopefully anyone else who comes across this will have a better understanding of how 'tsc' and 'tsconfig.json' interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved this awhile back but wanted to comment - I ran into a similar issue when learning typescript and found this [typescript outDir setting in tsconfig.json not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661027/typescript-outdir-setting-in-tsconfig-json-not-working)

It looks like maybe just compiling with `tsc` might be the way to go - it sounds like when we pass in file names like `tsc server.ts` it ignores the tsconfig.json file.

Typescript Documentation - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html